# Parsing xml from url in objective c

Tags: objective-c

i'm using the following code:

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
 NSLog(@"File found and parsing started");

 }


 - (void)parseXMLFileAtURL: (NSString *)URL;{


 NSString *agentString = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/525.27.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.2.1 Safari/525.27.1";
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
 [request setValue:agentString forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

 xmlFile = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];


 articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 errorParsing= NO;

 rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlFile];

 [rssParser setDelegate:self];

 // You may need to turn some of these on depending on the type of XML file you are parsing
 [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
 [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
 [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

 [rssParser parse];

 }


 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {

 NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error code %i", [parseError code]];
 NSLog(@"Error parsing XML: %@", errorString);


 errorParsing=YES;
 }


 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
 currentElement = [elementName copy];
 ElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"intro"]) {
 item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

 }

 }


 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
 [ElementValue appendString:string];
 }

 - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

 if (errorParsing == NO)
 {
 NSLog(@"XML processing done!");
 } else {
 NSLog(@"Error occurred during XML processing");
 }

 }
```

But on the line:

> xmlFile = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
>   returningResponse: nil error: nil ];

and:

```
rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlFile];

 [rssParser setDelegate:self];
```

I got 2 errors:

> **Use of undeclared identifier 'xmlFile'**

My .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ontfsViewController;


@interface artikels : UIViewController {

    ontfsViewController *detailViewController;

    IBOutlet UIWebView *errorView;

    //xml
    NSXMLParser *rssParser;
    NSMutableArray *articles;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSString *currentElement;
    NSMutableString *ElementValue;
    BOOL errorParsing;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ontfsViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

And i viewdidload:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:@"http://****.com/get_recent_posts.xml"];


}
```

And:

```
[rssParser setDelegate:self];


 **Sending 'artikels *const__strong' tot parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSXMLPARSERDELEGATE>**
```

Does anyone now how to fix it?

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you declare xmlFile. You'll need to specify its type - something like `id xmlFile = ....`

Comment: Daniel thanks fixed it with the answer of PeterPeuGuo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare xmlFile:

```
 NSData * xmlFile = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: n];
```

You also need to declare your class as:

```
 @interface artikels : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate> {
```

Comment: Thanks PeterPeiGuo i forgot that but on this line: [rssParser setDelegate: self]; i receive the error **Sending 'artikels *const__strong' tot parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSXMLPARSERDELEGATE>**

Comment: Thanks!! But in the viewdidload i have  [self parseXMLFileAtURL:@"http://****.com/get_recent_posts.xml"]; but when i fireup the app the only thing that i see is a white page. But in the NSLOgs that thing is picking 4 ''titles'' (xml feed contains 4 titles). Do you MAYBE know what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: in .xib i only have a view object and nothing more do i need a webview? Or something like that?

Comment: Hmm and is 'something' a webview or an other object?