# Showing XML in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on a XML view in xcode but the xml feed won't show. Do I need to place a object in the .xib file? And does anyone know which object?

[Need more code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461147/parsing-xml-from-url-in-objective-c)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
 
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:@"http://***.com/get_recent_posts.xml"];

   
    
}
```

Comment: How do you want to show the XML?

Comment: That's the big question i dont know how to show it i just want the title of the xml. i already Pick the title http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461147/parsing-xml-from-url-in-objective-c

Comment: show the code from -parseXMLFileATURL:

Comment: In herE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461147/parsing-xml-from-url-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show a string that you've already pulled out of the XML, use a UILabel.